# Latent Class Analysis: What's the difference between polytomous vs. dichotomous manifest variables?

Tags: r, categorical-data, latent-class

I am using `poLCA` in R to run a latent class analysis (LCA), and I'd like some help understanding the implications of using polytomous vs. dichotomous manifest variables.

I have three polytomous manifest variables, each with many levels (7, 12, and 14, to be precise). I originally dummy coded them all and ran it on 33 dichotomous variables, but I'm re-running it now as just three polytomous variables. The degrees of freedom for the model are different depending on how I do this (and measures of fit, etc. all change too, of course), so it's clearly not running the same model two ways, but two completely different models.

**Can someone explain how LCA with polytomous manifest variables differs from LCA on the same information represented in dichotomous variables?** Some software requires dichotomous manifest variables, but `poLCA` can handle polytomous, so I have the option to choose, and I don't feel like I understand the implications of the choice. 
Here's an example:

```
> set.seed(24601)
> df <- data.frame(V1=rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 10), 
+                  V2=rep(c("f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), 10), 
+                  V3=rep(c("k", "l", "m", "n", "o"), 10))
> rn <- data.frame(V1=factor(rbinom(1000, 4, .3), labels=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), 
+                  V2=factor(rbinom(1000, 4, .3), labels=c("f", "g", "h", "i", "j")), 
+                  V3=factor(rbinom(1000, 4, .3), labels=c("k", "l", "m", "n", "o")))
> df <- rbind(df, rn) # combine systematic and random data together
> summary(df)
 V1      V2      V3     
 a:234   f:243   k:258  
 b:433   g:437   l:408  
 c:286   h:254   m:280  
 d: 82   i: 91   n: 89  
 e: 15   j: 25   o: 15  
>
```

#### as polytomous

```
> as_poly <- poLCA(cbind(V1, V2, V3) ~ 1, df, nclass=2, maxiter = 10000)
Conditional item response (column) probabilities,
 by outcome variable, for each class (row) 

$V1
               a      b      c      d      e
class 1:  0.2277 0.4202 0.2781 0.0691 0.0049
class 2:  0.0054 0.0649 0.0158 0.4792 0.4347

$V2
               f      g      h      i      j
class 1:  0.2366 0.4244 0.2473 0.0777 0.0139
class 2:  0.0000 0.0506 0.0000 0.4849 0.4645

$V3
               k      l      m      n      o
class 1:  0.2506 0.3973 0.2726 0.0761 0.0034
class 2:  0.0263 0.0000 0.0000 0.4713 0.5024

Estimated class population shares 
 0.9781 0.0219 

Predicted class memberships (by modal posterior prob.) 
 0.9781 0.0219
```

Here's the fit, df, etc.:

```
========================================================= 
Fit for 2 latent classes: 
========================================================= 
number of observations: 1050 
number of estimated parameters: 25 
residual degrees of freedom: 99 
maximum log-likelihood: -4122.564 

AIC(2): 8295.129
BIC(2): 8419.043
G^2(2): 139.2114 (Likelihood ratio/deviance statistic) 
X^2(2): 139.9829 (Chi-square goodness of fit)
```

#### as dichotomous

```
> library(psych) # for dummy.code()
> library(dplyr) # for pipe and mutate_if
> df_dich <- cbind(dummy.code(df$V1), dummy.code(df$V2), dummy.code(df$V3)) %>% 
+   as.data.frame() %>% 
+   mutate_if(is.numeric, as.factor) 
> 
> as_dich <- poLCA(cbind(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o) ~ 1, df_dich, nclass=2, maxiter = 10000)
Conditional item response (column) probabilities,
 by outcome variable, for each class (row) 

$a
               0      1
class 1:  0.7849 0.2151
class 2:  0.7716 0.2284

$b
               0      1
class 1:  0.5767 0.4233
class 2:  0.5954 0.4046

$c
               0      1
class 1:  0.7208 0.2792
class 2:  0.7325 0.2675

$d
               0      1
class 1:  0.9222 0.0778
class 2:  0.9217 0.0783

$e
               0      1
class 1:  0.9954 0.0046
class 2:  0.9788 0.0212

$f
               0      1
class 1:  1.0000 0.0000
class 2:  0.6036 0.3964

$g
          0 1
class 1:  0 1
class 2:  1 0

$h
               0      1
class 1:  1.0000 0.0000
class 2:  0.5856 0.4144

$i
               0      1
class 1:  1.0000 0.0000
class 2:  0.8515 0.1485

$j
               0      1
class 1:  1.0000 0.0000
class 2:  0.9592 0.0408

$k
               0      1
class 1:  0.7689 0.2311
class 2:  0.7439 0.2561

$l
               0      1
class 1:  0.5652 0.4348
class 2:  0.6444 0.3556

$m
               0      1
class 1:  0.7437 0.2563
class 2:  0.7259 0.2741

$n
               0      1
class 1:  0.9268 0.0732
class 2:  0.9070 0.0930

$o
               0      1
class 1:  0.9954 0.0046
class 2:  0.9788 0.0212

Estimated class population shares 
 0.4162 0.5838 

Predicted class memberships (by modal posterior prob.) 
 0.4162 0.5838
```

Here's the fit, df, etc.:

```
========================================================= 
Fit for 2 latent classes: 
========================================================= 
number of observations: 1050 
number of estimated parameters: 31 
residual degrees of freedom: 1019 
maximum log-likelihood: -6420.786 

AIC(2): 12903.57
BIC(2): 13057.23
G^2(2): 4735.655 (Likelihood ratio/deviance statistic) 
X^2(2): 315556.7 (Chi-square goodness of fit)
```

You'll notice the degrees of freedom change, so it's clearly running two different models (and measures of fit, etc. change as well, of course).